# Insert Two List of values in play framework SQL anorm

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, playframework-2.3, anorm

Currently I am working on Playframework. I need to insert two `List` values into the database by using Anorm. One is `names: List[String]` and another one is `numbers: List[Int]`, and they both have the same size.

I need to insert first position of `names` and first position of `numbers List` in same `Row` in `Database Table` like wise need to insert all values in the both `Lists`.

I tried :

```
 for (no<- 0 to (names.size-1)) {

        SQL(
          """
          insert into table(NAME,NUMBER)
          values(
          names[{no}],numbers[{no}]
          )
        """).on(          
            'no-> no
            ).executeUpdate()
      }
```

It gives me the below error `[MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[0],numbers[0]`

and I also tried with

```
 for (name<- names;number<- numbers) {

    SQL(
      """
      insert into table(NAME,NUMBER)
      values(
      {name},{number}
      )
    """).on(            
        'name-> name,
        'number-> number
        ).executeUpdate()
  }
```

but it was act as `two for loops` like in java.

```
for(){
  for(){}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL statement with `names[{no}]` cannot work in any way: the database doesn't have the Scala value `names`.

You can use `.zipped`:

```
scala> (List("A", "B"), List(1.2F, 34.5F)).zipped.foreach { (str, f) => println(s"zipped: $str -> $f") }
zipped: A -> 1.2
zipped: B -> 34.5
```

Then the Anorm execution would be as following.

```
(names, numbers).zipped.foreach { (name, num) =>
  SQL"insert into table(NAME,NUMBER) values($name, $num)".executeUpdate()
}
```

Comment: I have another variable 'userId' for insertion. I used the below code but It has given a error 
 `SQL"insert into table(NAME,NUMBER,USER_ID) values($name, $num,{userid})".on('userid -> userid).executeUpdate()`

Comment: I write this `insertion` query inside one `function` which has `userid` as `parameter`.

Comment: I got below error `[MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1]`

Comment: Check your SQL statement syntax

Comment: this is my code I couldn't find the error   `def inserDetails(userid: Int, numbers: List[Int],names: List[String]) = {

 (names, numbers).zipped.foreach { (name,num) =>
  SQL"insert into test(NAME,NUMBER,USER_ID) values($name, $num,{userid})"
  .on('userid -> userid)
  .executeUpdate()
}  

}`

Comment: It gives me this error `[MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1]`

Comment: If I use without sending `userid` that `query` executes successfully.
 `(names, numbers).zipped.foreach { (name,num) =>
  SQL"insert into test(NAME,NUMBER) values($name, $num)" 
  .executeUpdate()
}`

Comment: Initially I inserted the `NUMBER,NAME` values then I updated the `USER_ID` columns based on these Lists values

Answer (score 0):

You should combine the two lists first using `zip`, so you have a single list where each list element is a tuple of name and number:

```
val names = List("bob", "steve", "frank")

val numbers = List(1,2,3)

val name_and_numbers = names zip numbers

name_and_numbers.foreach{ tuple =>
  println(s"name: ${tuple._1} number: ${tuple._2}")
}
```

Comment: I guess `(names, numbers).zipped` is more efficient in this case.

Comment: @cchantep can you explain why that's more efficient?

Comment: @mattinbits I tried your code too. but it too shows the same error `[MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1]`

Comment: `val name_and_numbers = names zip numbers`

`name_and_numbers.foreach{ tuple =>

   SQL"insert into table(NAME,NUMBER,USER_ID) values(${tuple._1}, ${tuple._2},{userid})".on('userid -> userid).executeUpdate()
  
}`

Comment: `.zipped` is a lazy view: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.IterableViewLike$Zipped

Comment: Thanks that's interesting